# Optimise Pandas.series conversion to a set

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am working on a data transforming project. I am taking in a `csv` that has 1 million records and trying to segregate them into individual `txt` files. The problem is that it takes a lot of time to process. We're talking more that 5 mins for each column here. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd

print("Reading CSV")
data_set = pd.read_csv(address_file_path, low_memory=False, index_col=1)
print("Reading Completed")
a_name = set(data_set.loc[:, 'A'])
print("A done")
b_name = set(data_set.loc[:, 'B'])
print("B Done")
c_name = set(data_set.loc[:, 'C'])
print("C Done")
d_name = set(data_set.loc[:, 'D'])
print("D done")
e_name = set(data_set.loc[:, 'E'])
print("E done")
f_name = set(data_set.loc[:, 'F'])
print("F done")

print("Data Transformed")
```

It does A quite quickly considering that the `Pandas.Series` has 1 million records but the repetition is such that it turns out to be only 36 entries but then it gets stuck I am not even sure the code finishes since I haven't seen it finish uptil now. 
How can I optimise it to work faster?

---

```
Unnamed: 0                           1
A                           NaN
B               Job Applicant;UP
C              USA
D                       California
E      Alice neh tratma
F                      Bharuhana
I                           NaN
J                           NaN
K                            SH 5
L                            NaN
M                            NaN
N                            NaN
O                            NaN
P                            NaN
Q                            NaN
```

Comment: If you are only writing to a file, try `pd.unique`, which is faster than set builder.

Comment: @ayhan I just pass in the Pandas.Series to it?

Comment: Yeah. Either `pd.unique(df['A'])` or `df['A'].unique()`. You can continue using loc too, of course.

Comment: @ayhan but what if I want to perform some operations on it before I write it down? For e.g. If I want to split some items based on ` ; ` and then write it to a file. How do I go about it then?

Comment: @iam.Carrot take a look at this question, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129713/fastest-way-to-find-all-unique-elements-in-an-array-with-cython

Comment: @DSM I am running a 16GB ram system with intel core i5 7thGen. My memory utilization by pycharm goes upto 1 GB.

Comment: Then something's definitely wrong; the set operation should take only seconds.  Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: @DSM that's all there is to the code. I can't share my dataset since it's way too huge and sized. I don't understand the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DSM I've added the read CSV part just incase it's of any relevance

Comment: @iam.Carrot can you add atleast `data_set.loc[0, 'A']` so we can see what kind of data we are dealing with. If its a pandas question no data no use

Comment: @iam.Carrot: please reread the MCVE page, and follow it up with this Q/A on [good pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).  We can't help with what we can't reproduce.

Comment: @DSM I've added the first entry of the dataset. All columns contain text (a bunch of strings)

Comment: @Dark I've added the first entry

Comment: Thanks, now I see what's going on.

Comment: @DSM great, thank god it provides more insight since I had literally have nothing else for it to be a MCVE. Please share where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're hitting this problem:

```
In [17]: s = pd.Series([np.nan]*3)

In [18]: set(s)
Out[18]: {nan, nan, nan}

In [19]: s[0]
Out[19]: nan

In [20]: s[0] is s[1]
Out[20]: False
```

nan can be a quirky little beast, because it's not equal to itself, and in this context the returned values aren't even identical to each other.  This is a terrible case for the hash lookup.

Either drop the nans manually or use `.unique()`.  After

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10**6,6)))
df.iloc[::2] = np.nan
```

I get

```
In [26]: %time z = set(df[0].dropna())
CPU times: user 128 ms, sys: 40 ms, total: 168 ms
Wall time: 174 ms

In [27]: %time z = df[0].unique()
CPU times: user 72 ms, sys: 12 ms, total: 84 ms
Wall time: 88.9 ms
```

and I gave up waiting for `set(df[0])` to finish.

In general, you're going to want to avoid mixing Python-level and numpy/pandas-level functions.  The latter tend to be faster even in cases where you're not hitting this weird corner case.

In your code, you could do

```
set(data_set.loc[:, 'A'].unique())
```

if you want to keep the NaN or `set(data_set.loc[:, 'A'].dropna().unique())` if you don't.  For many purposes you wouldn't even need to convert to a set, but if you're more familiar with its methods you can keep it.

Comment: great! would you be able to edit a line of code from my question as I am a little new to the python environment. It'll  be of great help

Comment: Also we can do `set(df["0"].astype(str))` since OP has object columns, though it cant beat the `unique()`

Comment: Great! It works perfectly. Thanks for the help. I shall remember it. Dropping the `NaN` manually wouldn't have been great as I'd like to keep my code immune to such datasets. the `unique()` works perfectly well. I didn't get the `.dropna().unique()` in terms of what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Er, `dropna` drops the nans, otherwise you'll wind up with a NaN in your set and not just strings.